# Select a specific column based on another column's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
ID | Type | Val0 | Val1
1  |  0   |  A   | NULL
2  |  1   | NULL |  B
```

I need to select `Val0` when the type is 0, and `Val1` when the type is 1, and `ValN` when type is N...

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of expected output?

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE ID = 1  -- A`

Comment: Just a quick comment: if you have tables like this, you should really consider a different schema.  Your database almost certainly does not follow the entity-relationship model.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why you are storing Val0, Val1... in different columns, in the first place?

Comment: I don't have a choice, it's a table from Telerik's Sitefinity.

Comment: Same problem. Not working on Sitefinity, but you don't always have control over your source tables unfortunately.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN Type = 0 THEN Val0
          WHEN Type = 1 Then Val1
          .
          .
          WHEN Type = N Then ValN
       END 
  FROM tbl
```

Comment: This apparently does have a problem though if you're using a table from another database, because apparently Sql Server then imposes a maximum number of cases of 10... which is pretty small.

Answer (score 3):

The way I read this, you need to use UNION:

```
SELECT a.val0
  FROM TABLE a
 WHERE a.type = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.val1
  FROM TABLE a
 WHERE a.type = 1
UNION ALL ...
```

UNION ALL doesn't remove duplicates, and is faster than UNION (because it removes duplicates).

Doing this dynamically is possible.

Comment: I interpreted it to be "give me a single value back based on the given type". But you may be totally right. It was good to ask for an expected output :).

Comment: @dcp: I've been bitten too many times my incorrect assumptions - I ask & wait while watching to see if it made sense to anyone else

Answer (score 2):

For low values of N, you can do it ad-hoc using the [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html), like `CASE Type WHEN 0 THEN Val0 WHEN 1 THEN Val1 END`. If your N is bigger, you should probably normalize your database (i.e. put ID => ValN mappings in a different table).

Comment: The CASE statement works well. The normalization suggestion is good, but not always possible, when you are integrating with someone elses database. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

See CASE statement
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx