# Selecting a column based on another column's value with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

My question is similar to the one here: [Select a specific column based on another column's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338710/select-a-specific-column-based-on-another-columns-value) but in LINQ, using VS2010, C#, .Net 4.0 and LINQ to Entities

Here's the snippet I'm having an issue with:

```
var BillingNumbers = (from o in mycontext.MyOrders
                    where o.Status.Description.Trim().ToUpper().Equals("SHIPPED")
                    && (o.ActualShipDate >= date1.Date && o.ActualShipDate < date2.Date)
                    select new
                            {BillingNumber = (
                          o.SiteID == "NYC"? o.NYCBillingNumber.Trim():
                          o.SiteID == "DAL" ? o.DallasBillingNumber.Trim(): "unknown") 
                          });
             foreach (var billingnumber in BillingNumbers)
             {
                sqlcmd = MyDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand("MyBillingNumberSP") as SqlCommand;
                sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = Int32.Parse(Settings.Default.SQL_COMMAND_TIMEOUT.ToString());
                MyDatabase.AddInParameter(sqlcmd, "@BillingNumber", DbType.String, billingnumber);
                MyDatabase.AddOutParameter(sqlcmd, "@MyOutputParam", DbType.Boolean, 1);
                LobjDS = MyDatabase.ExecuteDataSet(sqlcmd);  //GETTING AN ERROR HERE
                bool JobbingApplied = Convert.ToBoolean(MyDatabase.GetParameterValue(sqlcmd, "@MyOutputParam"));
                Console.WriteLine(billingnumber);
             }
```

The ExecuteDataSet command throws an InvalidCastException with the message:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a <>f__AnonymousType0`1 to a String.

What is wrong and why is this anonymous type throwing an error when attempted to interpret it as string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
MyDatabase.AddInParameter(sqlcmd, "@BillingNumber", DbType.String, billingnumber);
```

with

```
MyDatabase.AddInParameter(sqlcmd, "@BillingNumber", DbType.String, billingnumber.BillingNumber);
```

`var billingnumber` is a anonymous type with one string property `BillingNumber`. You need to reference that property, it is not automatically convertible to its first member.

An alternative is to replace

```
select  new
{   BillingNumber = (
    o.SiteID == "NYC"? o.NYCBillingNumber.Trim():
    o.SiteID == "DAL" ? o.DallasBillingNumber.Trim(): "unknown") 
}
```

with

```
select (
    o.SiteID == "NYC"? o.NYCBillingNumber.Trim():
    o.SiteID == "DAL" ? o.DallasBillingNumber.Trim(): "unknown")
```

Then you don't need the anonymous type at all.

Comment: Thank you.

Is there a more elegant way than billingnumber.BillingNumber?

Comment: you can change your select to `select 
                          o.SiteID == "NYC"? o.NYCBillingNumber.Trim():
                          o.SiteID == "DAL" ? o.DallasBillingNumber.Trim(): "unknown")` (which will return an `IEnumerable<string>`) and you can then leave the rest of your code as-is