# Snowflake: select column based on value inside a VARIANT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like this:

| Old_Values | A | B | C | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"A": null} | 2 |  |  | 1 |
| {"A": 1, "B": "A string"} | 2 | "Another string" |  | 2 |
| {"C": [1,2,3]} |  |  | [4,5,6] | 3 |

The column `Old_Values` is a VARIANT type with dicts. Inside it, the old columns might or might not exist. As you can see, in row 1, it stores only the previous values of `A`, and in row 3, it stores the previous value of `C`.

Some properties of this table:

- The keys inside the dict are guaranteed to be the names of columns in the table.
- There will be one kind of type mismatch case here, that is `null - non null`, which can be seen in Row 1. For example, since `A` is of type `INT`, it is guarantee that the values of the dict `"A"` inside `Old_Values` will have either type `null` or `INT`.

I want to make a table that captures all the changes that happen inside this. This is the desired result:

| ID | Column_Changed_Name | Old_Value | Current_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | B | "A string" | "Another string" |
| 3 | C | [1,2,3] | [4,5,6] |

Explanation:

- For row with `ID=1`, there's only one changed value so that there's only one row for `ID=1`.
- For row with `ID=2`, there's two changed that happened, so the all changes table has two rows for this `ID=2`.
- The same thing can be said with `ID=3`.

The best one I have tried so far is I use LATERAL flatten to get the previous values, but I do not know how to get the current value as a column:

```
SELECT 
    A.ID,
    F.KEY as Column_Changed_name,
    F.VALUE as Old_value
FROM A_FANCY_TABLE_NAME A,
LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => A.Old_Values) F;
```

Doing a For-Loop or CASE here would be very time-consuming since my table is about 20M rows. Plus, it has about a hundred columns, so I am looking for a general solution of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338710/select-a-specific-column-based-on-another-columns-value).

Note that I am open to any kind of code format - SQL, Stored Procedure (although any language is OK, but I prefer Python or JavaScript), etc.

EDIT: not sure if this will make the job easier, but the column names are known beforehand. It is just the number of values and values inside `Old_Values` are unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - modified with A as Int type column and added support to handle type mismatch. Please note - all columns (A, B and C) should be of similar type for unpivot to work.

```
select id, column_changed_name, old_value[column_changed_name]::varchar as old_value, current_value           
from (SELECT old_value,A::varchar AS A,B::varchar AS B,c::varchar AS C,id from a_fancy_table_name)
    unpivot(current_value for column_changed_name in (A,B,C))
WHERE current_value <> '' 
order by id;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEMP.a_fancy_table_name 
(
old_value VARIANT,
A int,
B varchar(200),
C varchar(200),
ID varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO TEMP.a_fancy_table_name 
        SELECT object_insert(object_construct(),'A',parse_json('NULL')) AS OLD_VALUE,2 AS A,'' AS B,'' AS C,'1' AS ID
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT object_construct('A',1::VARIANT, 'B','A string'::VARIANT) , 2, '"Another string"', '', '2'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT object_construct('C',[1,2,3]),null, '', '[4,5,6]','3';
    
SELECT * FROM TEMP.a_fancy_table_name;
```

Comment: I forget to add that the values inside the `Old_Values` column can be null, such as `{"A": null}`. Your code is not able to handle that `null` part. Can you help me to add the changes that I need to handle that as well? Only the case `null - non null` causes type mismatch. The values inside from that moment will be the same for all columns.

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu - edited now..pls check

Comment: It works flawlessly. Ty!